# Apply Limit query within a range value in SugarORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

```
Select.from(Records.class).orderBy("DATE DESC").limit("41, 60").list();
```

Here, i am getting 60 rows from my Record Table which is from 1 to 60. I need rows starting from 41 till 60. 
Any answer or suggestion how to get this.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer,

Select.from(Records.class).orderBy("DATE DESC").limit("41, 60").OFFSET 40.list();

offset basically skip the number of rows from top while returning the value. So, now we get sorted result for first 60 rows and then offset top 40 will get us 20 records from row 40 to row 60 , which is expected.